# Size of the audio in seconds

Tags: android

How do I know the file size in seconds mp4?

Comment: I read a SDK did not find. But the Android OS as it determines the length of the file in seconds when you select a track. So it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are playing it back with `MediaPlayer`, use `getDuration()` to find out its duration.

Otherwise, you will need to find a third-party library that can read the MP4 file metadata to get you that information.